# How do I import modules that are used inside a Python 3 file?

Tags: python-3.x, import

I have the following code in myfile.py

```
def show_path():
    print(os.getcwd())
```

In Jupyter notebook, I have the following (which runs fine):

```
import os
from myfile.py import show_path
```

However, when I run the following:

```
show_path()
```

I get 'name 'os' is not defined' error. But when I simply type:

```
os.getcwd()
```

I get the path, which I understand. But I don't understand why running show_path() doesn't do the same thing? Is it necessary to have import os inside my myfile.py file? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import os in your module, its import list is different then that of your notebook.  Since you did not import it in your module, it wa unavailable when your module was parsed.

Comment: Thanks. In my actual code, I have many functions which call each other and other Python modules. Should I place them all in one file (say file.py) with all import statements at the top? Should I also then individually import functions from file.py?

Comment: @Murchack
That depends on what you need, if you want to demo the code it should go in the notebook, if you just need it as a utility, you can put it in a separate module.